# How to denote the aggregation of values into a vector?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

How do I denote that I am aggregating values into a vector?

For example, I have a set of values $F$ in which a function $fun$ will be applied. Finally, a vector is build with the results.

For example, if $F = \{a,b\}$ and $fun(a) = 1, fun(b) = 2$, how can I denote that I'm assembling the vector: [1 2]?

Will a cartesian product suffice?

$$
 V = \prod_{e \in F} fun(e)
$$

Or should I use other operation?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "vector"? The space of maps $F\mapsto \mathbb R$ under pointwise addition and scalar multiplication is certainly a vector space in which $fun$ is a vector - and, even more, this tends to be a productive way to think about vectors when they arise this way.

Comment: I guess you mean *tuple* rather than *vector*. A tuple is a finite ordered list of elements, whereas a vector, which may be represented as a tuple, is a an element of a vector space.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to order the elements of $F$ into a given vector $\mathbf{f} \in F^n$, where $F^n = F \times F \times ... \times F$ $n$ times (that is, if the elements of $F$ are distinct; otherwise you are using a multiset). This will allow for a reasonable input representation for a vector-valued function.

To indicate that you are assembling a vector, you may want to establish a vector-valued function $\mathbf{v} : F^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ that is defined such that

$$\mathbf{v}_i(\mathbf{f}) = fun(\mathbf{f}_i), i \in [n].$$

This is a reasonable way to indicate that you are assembling a vector using the output of the function $\mathbf{v}$.